# Duplicate reopened: keep the link to the near-duplicate

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

Currently, when a question is marked as duplicate, the comment "possible duplicate..." is removed and a banner containing the duplicate link is added to the question.

However, now when the question is reopened, the link to the suspected duplicate is gone. Of course reopening happened because the duplicate wasn't deemed a pure duplicate, but still the originally linked question + answers could have much value for later visitors.

So, could the link to the "near-duplicate" be preserved when a closed question is reopened?

**Edit**
Seeing [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283203/861716) about duplicate targets getting deleted: Of course we don't want to maintain dead links. So could we just add the text "(near duplicate)" to the link in the **Linked** section? I think that these links just disappear when a question is deleted?

Comment: I believe the question will still be listed in the Linked section in the sidebar, even once the comment is removed.

Comment: You're actually right (didn't notice that). But it's is less visible than the original link. - as I said: didn't notice that :)

Comment: But if we leave the comment there, people who don't know better will try to vote to close the question as a duplicate again thinking it's an unresolved duplicate vote. How do you propose to make the link more visible while avoiding this sort of confusion?

Comment: This seems like an obvious suggestion to me, so you may have considered it already, but I don't see any drawbacks: why not, when a question is closed as a duplicate and the duplicate is not in the comments any longer, and someone votes to re-open (or once the question is re-opened, whichever works best), add a comment "not a duplicate of (link)" in much the same spirit as the original "possible duplicate of (link)" comment?

Comment: @hvd Exactly! Ready for release :)

Comment: Could you provide an example of the "value" of such a link?  If it isn't a duplicate, then it is probably only related, so it is in the sidebar close to the other related questions.

Comment: Well, @psubsee2003, they're hard to find. I can see the ones I reopened myself, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27756900/861716) could be an example. But I'm a bit wary of giving one examples (or even some), because too often this reduces a meta issue into a discussion between people agreeing and disagreeing about the specific example. I just wanted to point out a practice I often don't feel happy about, trying to find out if others experience this as well.

Comment: @GertArnold I wasn't referring to specific question examples - I mean scenarios in which a "near duplicate" link would be beneficial.  Why would keeping the link closer than the "linked" sidebar after 5 members of the community decided it wasn't a duplicate be valuable?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Ah OK. Because likewise, before that 5 others decided it was (if no dupe hammer was involved). Linked questions can be anything. People often link to their own previous question when they move on to a next step (while in fact they should create a new stand-alone question). Besides that, linked questions are often found in comments explaining why they were linked. A "near-duplicate" comment would point out this reason for a previous false duplicate. This would also prevent others from marking the question as dupe again (although I must admit I can't remember ever having seen that).