# Duplicate Question removed

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5708192/368167

The question is closed a duplicate of another question, the title and link of the other question appear as usual. If you try to open the other question, however, you get a "Page Not Found" error.

if the *original* duplicate, which is supposed to be older and more informative, had to be deleted, then the duplicates should also be deleted alike IMHO. Maybe automatically or with a community manager review.

Comment: Frankly, both should have been deleted, given that recommendations (books or otherwise), are now off-topic.

Comment: @Oded, [that is unfair](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/960757).

Comment: @TLama - the exception that proves the rule. That one is actually being actively maintained (last edit - last week, for a question that was asked almost 7 year ago)

Comment: @Oded, how do you know that someone would not maintain a similar collaborative answer?

Comment: OK, now what about the issue *in general*? What should we do when a duplicate target is deleted? As psubsee2003 says, they leave us with useless signposts. At StackOverflow we always try to remove redundancy and clutter. Does this problem occur often enough to want to do something about it?

Comment: "how do you know that someone would not maintain a similar collaborative answer?" Because they didn't.  [Good and fast learning jquery Book?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5708192/1288) was asked in 2011. It got one answer, then sat undisturbed for nearly four years.

Comment: But please only delete duplicate questions without a good answer manually - whatever the criterias for a good answer might be. Questions that are closed as a duplicate can contain helpfull answers, no matter if the duplicate exists anymore

Comment: @Oded actually the most succinct edit was in Dec 9 '14, the latest just changed "used" to "to use"

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/168802/1026459

Answer (score 28):

I agree with this idea completely.  Duplicates are supposed to provide a roadmap to users with the same problem to hopefully find an answer to their problem.  Nothing is more frustrating than being told your question may have an answer over "there" only to find "there" is a dead link.

When a duplicate target is deleted, all questions connected to it should be candidates for deletion.  They probably should be only subject to deletion pending some sort of manual review, either by the community via the review queues, or by a moderator via a moderator queue.

Using the existing review queues, you can just throw any linked duplicate question into the reopen queue with an explicit notice that the duplicate target was deleted.  If the community chooses to reopen the question, then reopen it, if not, then delete it.

At no point should we silently delete content without allowing someone (preferably multiple someones) to at least look at it.  However, the point is that if the duplicate target was deleted, that should suggest that the duplicate question is also a candidate for deletion.  But the system can be set up to help prevent deletion of good content by implementing some checks, such as:

- Favoring reopening over deletion in the review queue by requiring more than a 3-2 voting to not reopen.
- Establish a question score threshold for deletion.  Questions with a score `>x` could favor reopening or score `<y` could favor deletion.
- Consider existing answers.  If there are upvoted answers then favor reopening.
- Consider incoming duplicate links.  If the question is a duplicate target for other questions, then the default action should be to reopen so as not to set of a chain reaction of deletion up the chain
- Consider the number of duplicate links to the now deleted target.  If multiple questions were closed as a duplicate to that single question, then possibly the duplicate chain just needs reorganized with a new target.  This is also to prevent a chain reaction of deletion up the various branches of the duplicate chain.

Comment: I think at the very least, the "duplicate" message and link should automatically be removed. I'm not sure exactly how I feel about automatic deletion of the questions one way or the other.

Comment: @RubberDuck Blindly reopening the question only allows a potentially poor question to remain on the site.  And I don't like automatic (silent) deletion.  I'd rather have someone look at them first.  The point is if the duplicate target is delete worthy, then there is a good chance that the duplicate question is as well.  But if it isn't then someone will be able to review.  You can add some additional thresholds the process to favor reopening, and also add checks based on post score or answer score to also limit what gets deleted,

Comment: I can agree with that @psubee2003. I just wanted to make sure we're not proposing blindly *deleting* questions either.

Comment: @RubberDuck added a new blurb to cover that

Comment: What if the duplicate questions were reopened and automatically flagged for (say) mod attention?  That way, the "this is a duplicate" banner vanishes immediately, we favor keeping it open over closing/deleting it, and it still gets looked at by a human.

Comment: @Kevin I hate to give more work to the mods, although this is probably rare enough that it wouldn't be a huge burden.  It would be ok if we did that, but ultimately it should be the community's decision in my opinion, so I'd rather the community handle it.  i go back to the idea that if the question was on-topic and good enough, then in most cases the duplicate target wouldn't have been deleted.