# Do not delete comments when question is marked as duplicate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, duplicate-questions, deleted-comments

If a comment underneath a question contains a link to another question and the question is subsequently closed as duplicate of this question, the comment containing this link is automatically deleted.

I'm not sure what exact rule is applied here, but this automatic deletion has some clear drawbacks.

Also see this 3 year old question: [Do not automatically remove hand-written comments when closing as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate). Or this one: [Make the automatic deletion of "possible duplicate of" comments more precise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344519/make-the-automatic-deletion-of-possible-duplicate-of-comments-more-precise), which is unanswered.

I would like to renew **the request not to delete those comments**.

Reasons are: Those comments might be of the form:

- > *"This could be a duplicate of _link1_, _link2_, _link3_."*

  If then the question is closed as duplicate of link1, the two other links are gone, even though they might help the questioner and other future readers.
- > *"This question **is not** a duplicate of _link_"*

  The argument will be deleted, despite being potentially useful or correct.
- > *"I found this link, but it doesn't help because _reason A_"*

  Same as above.
- > *"I marked this question as duplicate of _link_, because _reason A_, _reason B_"*

  The reasons for being a duplicate would be deleted, despite being useful for the questioner to know how their next question should be phrased or what not to ask next.

(If people are interested in a real-world example: [see my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087946/winddata-for-several-points-in-time-x-axis-plotted-against-two-different-me?noredirect=1#comment85184394_49087946) and imagine it had been written by someone other then the person closing the question.)

Equally, if a question gets reopened after being closed, the link to the in that case very-closely-related question is not there anymore - see [Duplicate reopened: keep the link to the near-duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283135/duplicate-reopened-keep-the-link-to-the-near-duplicate?rq=1)

**Edit**: I do not quite see how this feature request has been sufficiently handled in the question now marked as duplicate, since that post is neither declined nor does it have any answers arguing against it. I wrote [this new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364131/how-to-renew-an-old-feature-request), asking how such renewals of old feature request should be handled instead.

Comment: Sort of hard to vote on this - as feature request I completely support it (as you can see from my feature request you've linked to), but this is exactly the same request... I think I'll vote on  it as on feature request...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, and although the majority seemed to support it, nothing has changed in the past 3 years. Any better idea on how to bring this issue up again, other than opening a new feature request about the old topic?

Comment: No better ideas...Reality of the FR seem to be "declined due to being ignored"... So far only recommendation is to just stick extra link into such comments (MCVE, [ edit ], or just another useful link) to  prevent the match.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, that is possible when I write a comment myself, and then close the question. But not in the case someone else's useful comment contains that link.

Comment: So... that's why my comments link to dupes are deleted. I thought some moderator deletes it.

Comment: [MSE duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141414/179419) (from 2012...)

Comment: I am a bit in loss here. I thought that only the automatic comment when you flag a dup question gets removed. You gave many examples saying they get removed.

Comment: These are very valid concerns and I'm surprised nobody has acted if this has been known since 2012. I guess "top bars" was more important than core functionality.