# How to renew an old feature request?

Tags: support, meta, feature-request-process

This is a kind of meta meta question. 
I recently wrote this feature request

[Do not delete comments when question is marked as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364089/do-not-delete-comments-when-question-is-marked-as-duplicate)

A similar request was brought up already 3 years ago in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate). This has never been declined, nor does it have any answers which argue against it. Still, my feature request was closed as a duplicate of this old post. It now says

[image]

which is not really correct, because no real answer to it is given, other than suggestions on how to implement this feature.

Question: How should one renew an old feature request, which has not been declined or handled in any way?

---

Edit: In the comments, the post [Bringing attention to old meta questions (when you can't edit)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317708/bringing-attention-to-old-meta-questions-when-you-cant-edit) was brought to my attention. While the question is somehow similar as this one, the answer is not applicable. It suggests to either answer the old feature request, which is not doable - as I don't have an answer to it - I just have the similar request. Or to ask a new question (which is what I did, and that one got closed).

Comment: I would argue that you accomplished your goal of renewing discussion of the feature since to got fresh eyes on the original.

Comment: Very related, borderline duplicate: [Bringing attention to old meta questions (when you can't edit)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317708/bringing-attention-to-old-meta-questions-when-you-cant-edit).  Which ironically, this comment will be deleted if this is actually closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Regarding your edit, don't worry about an answer, not being an actual answer on meta.  Meta is actually combination of a discussion forum, bug tracker, feature request tracker, and support site force fit into the Q&A Engine.  So the rules that exist on the main site are much more relaxed on meta.  Consider leaving an "answer" structured as a justification or support for the request.  Or a reason why it needs done, or a suggestion for implementation

Comment: It's a pity that per-site metas don't have bounties. At least on MSE we can use bounties for these. Since the MSE/MSO split we can't do that on MSO anymore :-(

Comment: @S.L.Barth Although it was more of a placebo than anything, as it never really had much of an impact on SE's decision making.

Comment: slightly related: [Are any major improvements planned for the core Q&A engine? Is there any point in contributing relevant suggestions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343387/are-any-major-improvements-planned-for-the-core-qa-engine-is-there-any-point-i/)

Comment: Upvoted for the irony.

Answer (score 15):

There are a few ways.

**Edit or answer**
As was [pointed out by Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364141/812149), you could post an answer. Or edit the feature request. This will make the feature request active again.

But if you don't have anything to add or correct to the feature request, you have to go other ways.

**Chat**
You could raise the issue in chat. If you find a chatroom where people are sympathetic to the request (or even opposed to it...!) this could raise new interest. They could vote on it, or even post answers that you hadn't thought of yourself.

**Use MSE**
The particular feature request that inspired this question, would not just apply to Stack Overflow. It could apply to the entire Stack Exchange network.
So, you could request to migrate it to MSE, or post it on MSE.
Or, if the same feature request already exists on MSE, you could bounty it there.

These are the three things we can do right now. We could also ask for new ways to bring attention to old posts.
For example, we could ask to have bounties on per-site metas. Although the rep on a per-site meta is the rep one has on the main site, the per-site metas do keep track of one's "per-site meta rep" under the hood. Witness the fact that one can earn badges like Mortarboard and Legendary on a per-site meta, independent from the badges one has on the main site.
It would still be a big change, and I'm not sure the advantages would outweight the disadvantages. But it would be one way in which the system could be changed, to allow us to renew interest in old requests.

Comment: Please do state that answers should *at the very least* try to contribute to the discussion. Answers that only say "Bumping this feature request" will be deleted.

Answer (score 6):

If you see a feature request that you support, you can upvote it to show said support.

If you have a few points that you think you can add to the discussion of that feature request, you could post an answer to the question with your thoughts on that feature request.

If you feel that the points for/against that feature request have been changed significantly since it was originally asked, then you could post a new feature request.  If you post a new feature request you should be clearly indicating why the problems previously pointed out with that feature request no longer apply, significant new reasons for it that weren't discussed in the previous proposal, or changes to the proposal that address the problems pointed out with the previous proposal.  You should also be clearly indicating that you're aware of the past discussions, and explaining how your proposal address those previously pointed out problems.

Comment: What if no problems were pointed out? What if it was just ignored as happened in this case?

Comment: @Oleg Then either you have something more to add to the discussion (more reasons to support it, that weren't brought up before), or you don't.  Lots of feature requests are simply so uninteresting that people don't feel the need to discuss them at all.  Either you have something to add to the conversion to *make* people interested in it, or you don't.