# Can we please get an official policy for bumping old not-implemented feature requests

Tags: discussion, meta, feature-request-process

After having a question regarding implementing an old feature request closed today, and an answer on the actual old feature request deleted because "that's not what answers are for" ([despite this comment suggesting otherwise](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364131/how-to-renew-an-old-feature-request#comment562383_364131)), I now have run out of options to bring visibility to said old feature request.

[A previous question in this vein](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364131/how-to-renew-an-old-feature-request) never got an official answer, so please do not close this question as a duplicate of that one. **I am specifically asking for an official policy, so if you are not an employee or moderator, please do not post an answer here.**

If there is no official policy elucidated, I'm going to assume that posting useless answers is the policy.

Comment: I think that if you **only** want _official_ answers instead of community input, you may be best served by using the contact form instead of meta.

Comment: Your "answer" consisted entirely of *Still not done in 2018. Bumping so that hopefully this gets some eyes on it.* That falls short, by a long distance, from the advice in the comment, which qualifies posting an answer that  is *structured as a justification or support for the request*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My justification for the request boils down to "I agree with what the person asking the question wants it for". Do I copy-paste the question text as an answer then? Fact of the matter is, SO needs a better system for handling feature requests and the priority thereof, and if they aren't willing to provide that system, then we'll all have to make do.

Comment: That's just disagreeing that the feature hasn't yet been implemented. We can't make the company do anything there, posting an answer saying 'I want this feature too' is not going to have any more or less of an effect on the feature priority than voting on the proposal is going to have. What such an answer does do is create more *noise* around the proposal than a simple vote would have produced. We don't need noise.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an employee or moderator, but I'm going to post an answer despite your request.  The best "official" answer I can provide is to quote [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) in his answer to [Ideas for calling attention to questions in Meta of SE sites without bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216025/ideas-for-calling-attention-to-questions-in-meta-of-se-sites-without-bounty/216027#216027)

The 3rd bullet of his entire answer reads:

> Posting answers that contribute useful information to the discussion can encourage people to write their own

So yes, you should be posting answers that contribute useful information.  That is assuming ideas on how to implement, details as to why the feature is good, or why the idea won't work are considered "useful".