# Why did I not receive a notification for a ping in a comment in a question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments, comment-replies

I was pinged by the OP [in this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614629/php-overide-parent-return-type-in-child-method) and did not receive the notification ping for it (in the dropdown for recent messages) [in this commment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614629/php-overide-parent-return-type-in-child-method#comment105393112_59614629) by the OP, being:

> *@FunkFortyNiner That was a totally different question, had nothing to do with my question. That question as about the difference between a string (String) and an object, my question was about changing return types in PHP when using class inheritance. – Odyssee*.

Is there something wrong with the system today? This is the first time that this happens to me.

Edit:

I did receive [this ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614629/php-overide-parent-return-type-in-child-method#comment105393449_59614629) by another member just now.

> *@FunkFortyNiner If 3 the close votes are all for different reasons, it seems that the logic selects the first-voted reason as the one to display. That's what I've noted so far, anyway. With only 3 votes required now, it is more likely that all the votes will be for different reasons than when 5 were required. – Patrick Q*

So why is the one by the OP still not showing?

Edit #2:

My comment was removed and I don't know why that was. I asked the OP if what another posted as a possible duplicate answered the question or not. I have flagged that question for moderation.

Comment: Possible scenario: you VTC'd the question as dupe, a comment was automatically added, the question was closed, but OP was online. They saw the comment, went to the question and pinged you. You didn't have any other comments, so you weren't notified.

Comment: @double-beep Possibly, hard to say but even still; that should not have happened, IMHO.

Comment: @double-beep Exactly what happened. I did not leave the page as the question got closed, then I responded to foun forty niner's message..

Comment: So this *is* a bug then, or some other possible goblin running around starting fires and leaving LMHO!

Comment: @double-beep No wait; my comment was removed by someone, I did ask the OP if what another posted as a possible duplicate answered the question or not. I'll edit my question and flag for moderation.

Comment: @Odyssee That is because my comment was removed and I don't know why. I did not delete it, so something else caused this.

Comment: The duplicate closure caused that. Comments that seems related to the duplicate get deleted by the system. This is by design. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364089/do-not-delete-comments-when-question-is-marked-as-duplicate

Comment: @rene I thought of that also just a few minutes ago. So, what now?

Comment: Nothing. Let's go on with our life?

Comment: @rene I tend to agree, *but* nonetheless, I find that I inadvertently fell into an abyss :(

Comment: But that gives you another opportunity to practice your *climb out of an abyss* skill and it is pretty rewarding if you succeed ...

Comment: @rene You are right. I have to say though, that when I asked my question here earlier, I didn't notice my comment had been removed due to the duplicate closure. My comment was there for a good 5-10 mins if I do recall, and the OP didn't respond. When they did reply, was at about the same time that I voted to close as "unclear", as stated in the comments under the question. That's why I asked it here, and didn't notice it was deleted. An honest mistake of sorts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything happened in a relatively short period of time but here's the order of events:

- **15:40:16Z** - you post your comment.

  > Did [this comment/flag as a dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59614629/php-overide-parent-return-type-in-child-method/59614744#comment105392435_59614629) answer the question? Or should that flag be retracted?
- **15:46:06Z** - you cast the third vote needed to close, closing the question. Note, all three close votes were for different reasons and the "winning" reason was that it was a duplicate.
  Simultaneously - Community to deleted your comment and the one it linked to. Apparently the script that removes duplicate recommendation comments  thought your comment qualified.
- **15:46:29Z** - Odyssee responds to your comment. Since your comment has been deleted, you're technically not pingable any more, so you don't get a notification.

As confusing as this may have been, it is all by design. We intend that comments referring to a duplicate should be removed by the system (though, [how we do it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270643/do-not-automatically-remove-hand-written-comments-when-closing-as-duplicate) may be questioned) and we intend that users should not be pingable if they no longer have active comments on a question - this gives them a way to disable pings if they wish, by deleting their comments.

I've undeleted your comment but I'm not sure it makes sense since the comment you link to was removed (rightly) by Community when the question was closed. The close vote can no longer be retracted, so it may be more sensible for me to edit your comment to ask if the duplicate answers the question... but I avoid doing so in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand what happened, and I know that a flag as a possible duplicate in the comments  area automatically gets deleted whenever a question gets closed using, but what I don't understand is my comment being deleted which was linked to it. So comments that are directly referencing another also gets deleted automatically even though it was linked to the comment/flag in comments?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Looking at the code it seems that the comment did qualify but not specifically because it linked to the duplicate comment... the regex checks for the word duplicate or dupe and a single link to a question. You technically posted a comment link but... well... links to comments on questions look a lot like question links.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for clarifying that for me, cheers.